# logical volume that extended over two disks no longer works on new server

Tags: centos6, lvm

I have 2 1TB hard drives that had one logical volume of 1.7TB that extended over both hard drives. The previous server stopped working but both hard drives still seem fine. However I run into an issue when I try to start the system. The following is the output when it stops:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vg_admin-lv_root, 
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try 
dmesg | tail or so

mount: you must specify the filesystem type
...
mount: you must specify the filesystem type

Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
```

Right before this I see the normal centos loading screen. I am able to connect one of the hard drives via usb to a virtual machine in virtual box. If I run lvscan in this virtual machine I get:

```
WARNING: Device for PV SjdY0V-UVhQ-SfqN-I7Vg-s17Q-CP5M-z02f5g not found or rejected by filter
  inactive          '/dev/vg_admin/lv_root' [50.00 GiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/vg_admin/lv_home' [1.76 TiB] inherit
  inactive          '/dev/vg_admin/lv_swap' [5.86 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/cl/swap' [820.00 MiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/cl/root' [6.20 GiB] inherit
```

By running `modprobe dm-mod` I was able to make the inactive partitions active by running `vgchange -ay` after. It did promt me for `vg_admin/lv_home` saying that it refused activation of partial LV but I can still activate this via `--activationmode partial`.

Now when I try to mount this partial partition I get an error like this:

```
Buffer I/O error on dev dm-5, logical block 0 async page read
```

I get a similar error when trying to run `xfs_repair` and `fsck`.

I am hitting a wall at this point, I would like to recover the files on the hard drives, I believe most, if not all of the files are actually on the first hard drive since the partition should be nowhere near full. What else can I try to do to read the files from the hard drives? Maybe I can resize the lv?

The old server was a `hp proliant dl320e gen8`, I was not using the build in raid controller as far as I can remember. The server/computer im using now just has a simple TPower X79 motherboard with sata connections. The hard drives are Dell enterprise 7.2k rpm 1TB.

Comment: You can try `testdisk` utility to recover the files. It seems that this was no proper business environment, since two drives were combined in a dangerous way and there seems to be no backups...

Comment: I am able to copy files with `testdisk` so that might be my only option i guess